# How to convert a Windows path (with backslashes) to Unix format on Babun/Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, path, posix

I'm using Windows and writing shell scripts to run on Babun (a POSIX api).

I need to read a path from an environment variable, $USERPROFILE, and convert it to unix style (replace \ by /, c:\ by /c/) so I can use it later in the script.

The problem is whenever I echo the content of $USERPROFILE, the backslashes are interpreted as escaping characters and I get an unexpected result (letters "randomly" turn into special characters like \n, \f, etc). So I can't echo it into sed for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cygwin provides the very useful `cygpath` utility for converting Unix and Windows format paths.
From the [Cygwin User Guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)

> The `cygpath` program is a utility that converts Windows native filenames to
>   Cygwin POSIX-style pathnames and vice versa. It can be used when a Cygwin
>   program needs to pass a file name to a native Windows program, or expects to
>   get a file name from a native Windows program. Alternatively, `cygpath` can
>   output information about the location of important system directories in
>   either format.

It can convert to/from either Windows or DOS-style format paths, e.g. to print the Unix format of a Windows path:

```
$ cygpath -u "$USERPROFILE"
/cygdrive/c/Users/anthony
```

See the [Cygwin User Guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) for full details and `cygpath --help` for basic usage information.